# Data-Directed Programming SICP

Tags: scheme, sicp

I have been trying to comprehend data-directed programming in SICP but couldn't so far. I have some questions about it. This is the original code from SICP:

```
(define (make-table)
  (let ((local-table (list '*table*)))
    (define (lookup key-1 key-2)
      (let ((subtable
             (assoc key-1 (cdr local-table))))
        (if subtable
            (let ((record
                   (assoc key-2 (cdr subtable))))
              (if record (cdr record) false))
            false)))
    (define (insert! key-1 key-2 value)
      (let ((subtable
             (assoc key-1 (cdr local-table))))
        (if subtable
            (let ((record
                   (assoc key-2 (cdr subtable))))
              (if record
                  (set-cdr! record value)
                  (set-cdr! subtable(cons (cons key-2 value)

                                          (cdr subtable)))))
            (set-cdr! local-table(cons (list key-1 (cons key-2 value))

                                       (cdr local-table)))))
      'ok)
    (define (dispatch m)
      (cond ((eq? m 'lookup-proc) lookup)
            ((eq? m 'insert-proc!) insert!)(else (error "Unknown operation: TABLE" m))))
    dispatch))


(define (assoc key records)
  (cond ((null? records) false)
        ((equal? key (caar records)) (car records))
        (else (assoc key (cdr records)))))


(define operation-table (make-table))
(define get (operation-table 'lookup-proc))
(define put (operation-table 'insert-proc!))

(define (make-from-real-imag-rectangular x y)
  (attach-tag 'rectangular (cons x y)))

(define (make-from-mag-ang-polar r a)
  (attach-tag 'polar (cons r a)))

(define (make-from-real-imag x y)
  (make-from-real-imag-rectangular x y))

(define (make-from-mag-ang r a)
  (make-from-mag-ang-polar r a))

(define attach-tag cons)

(define type-tag car)

(define contents cdr)


(define (install-rectangular-package)
  ;;internal procedures
  (define (real-part z)(car z))
  (define (imag-part z)(cdr z))
  (define (make-from-real-imag)(cons x y))
  (define (magnitude z)
    (sqrt (+ (square (real-part z))
             (square (imag-part z)))))
  (define (angle z)
    (atan (imag-part z)(real-part z)))
  (define (make-from-mag-ang r a)
    (cons (* r (cos a))(* r (sin a))))
  
  ;;interface to the rest of the system
  (define (tag x)(attach-tag 'rectangular x))
  (put 'real-part '(rectangular) real-part)
  (put 'imag-part '(rectangular) imag-part)
  (put 'magnitude '(rectangular) magnitude)
  (put 'angle '(rectangular) angle)
  (put 'make-from-real-imag 'rectangular
       (lambda (x y) (tag (make-from-real-imag x y))))
  (put 'make-from-mag-ang 'rectangular
       (lambda (r a) (tag (make-from-mag-ang r a ))))
  'done)


(define (install-polar-package)
  ;; internal procedures
  (define (magnitude z) (car z))
  (define (angle z) (cdr z))
  (define (make-from-mag-ang r a) (cons r a))
  (define (real-part z) (* (magnitude z) (cos (angle z))))
  (define (imag-part z) (* (magnitude z) (sin (angle z))))
  (define (make-from-real-imag x y)
    (cons (sqrt (+ (square x) (square y)))
          (atan y x)))
  ;; interface to the rest of the system
  (define (tag x) (attach-tag 'polar x))
  (put 'real-part '(polar) real-part)
  (put 'imag-part '(polar) imag-part)
  (put 'magnitude '(polar) magnitude)
  (put 'angle '(polar) angle)
  (put 'make-from-real-imag 'polar
       (lambda (x y) (tag (make-from-real-imag x y))))
  (put 'make-from-mag-ang 'polar
       (lambda (r a) (tag (make-from-mag-ang r a))))
  'done)


(install-polar-package)
(install-rectangular-package)
```

Firstly, I couldn't get how to put an entry to the table using make-from-real-imag or make-from-mag-ang

```
(put 'make-from-real-imag 'rectangular
     (lambda (x y) (tag (make-from-real-imag x y))))
```

Could you just show me how to call this procedure exactly to put an entry ?

When I call get without putting any entry like this:

```
(get 'real-part '(rectangular))
```

it returns `(lambda (z) (car z))` why ? It should return as false if there is no entry in the table or is there a problem with my code ?

inside packages there are "interface to the rest of the system" parts in there how put procedure call selectors (real-part, imag-part, magnitude, angle) without any argument ?

```
(put 'real-part '(polar) real-part)
```

Comment: Code using these packages doesn't directly call the `make-from-real-imag` above (definition is missing its arguments, btw), or `get`/`put`. If "Generic selectors" and "Constructors for complex numbers" functions from SICP code (and called fns) are added they define a new `make-from-real-imag` etc, and then one can write eg `(magnitude (make-from-real-imag 3 4))`

Answer (score 2):

After I have seen Brian Harvey's cs61a lesson 16 which is about generic operators I have comprehended data directed programming a bit. Here is the youtube link of Brian Harvey's cs61a lesson 16 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgbBNEuHs2w

When we call packages, procedures are put on to the table as lambda functions. That's why when we call `(get 'real-part '(rectangular))`it returns as `(lambda (z) (car z))`

So `put` procedures are called with packages for example`(put 'real-part '(polar) real-part)` and this procedure takes `(define (real-part z) (* (magnitude z) (cos (angle z))))` as argument and put as an entry to the table

These procedures are continuation of above procedures in the book.

```
(define (map proc items)
  (if (null? items)
      nil
      (cons (proc (car items))
            (map proc (cdr items)))))

   
(define (apply-generic op . args)
  (let ((type-tags (map type-tag args)))
    (let ((proc (get op type-tags)))
      (if proc
          (apply proc (map contents args))
          (error
           "No method for these types: APPLY-GENERIC"
           (list op type-tags))))))
 

(define (real-part z) (apply-generic 'real-part z))
(define (imag-part z) (apply-generic 'imag-part z))
(define (magnitude z) (apply-generic 'magnitude z))
(define (angle z) (apply-generic 'angle z))

  
(define (make-from-real-imag x y)
  ((get 'make-from-real-imag 'rectangular) x y))
(define (make-from-mag-ang r a)
  ((get 'make-from-mag-ang 'polar) r a))
```

To create a complex number for rectangular representation for example I call:

```
(define c-num1 (make-from-real-imag 5 3))
```

now we have a `c-num1` object as `(rectangular 5 . 3)`

we can call any operation on this object with `apply-generic`

for example `(apply-generic 'real-part c-num1)` we get 5 or `(apply-generic 'imag-part c-num1)` we get 3 or we directly call `(real-part c-num1)` which is defined using `apply-generic`.